# Optimizing inventory checking for scalability

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

EDIT: For clarity

I have multiple inventories (`List<Item>`s named `items1`, `items2`, etc) in a instance of an inventory (`inventory`). I also have multiple copies of the slot list below (`slots1`).

At the moment, I have to copy out the entire for loop given for each set of items/slots. I have been trying for a couple of days to condense it down in an intelligent manner so I only have a single bit of code that runs through all of the inventories.

I'm specifically trying to find a solution by which I can say something like:
items = inventory.items1
slots = slots1

and then run the loop once for each pair, so if I have items1/slots1, items2/slots2, items3/slots3 it would run three times.

My current code:

In the inventory instance:

```
public List<Item> items1 = new List<Item>();
```

In the UI script:

```
InventorySlot1[] slots1 = itemsParent1.GetComponentsInChildren<InventorySlot1>();

for (int i = 0; i < slots1.Length; i++)
{
    if (i < inventory.items1.Count)
    {
        slots1[i].AddItem(inventory.items1[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        slots1[i].ClearSlot();
    }
}
```

There is a copy of the above code for each items/slots pair! I would like to make it so I only need one copy of this loop.

Comment: What do you start with (A)? what should the outcome be like (B), and what is the problem to get from A to B?

Comment: Im guessing you are trying to populate x slots, with the first x items from a list.. so, make 1 method that takes a list, and use the list instead of inventory.items1[i] just use invlist (as say the parameter)[i], and there you go

Comment: @BugFinder I'm sorry Im not exactly following, could you give me a code example?

Comment: make a function as explained say called showInv, and then you can call showInv(inventory.items1) or showInv(inventory.items2) ..

Comment: if `slots1` has lots of elements then you can use `Parallel.For` or `Parallel.ForEach`

Comment: also make sure `Slot` has sufficient capacity in backing `array` or `List<T>` otherwise it will create new array and move old elements in new array. which will cost to GC as well as CPU while moving elements to new collection